# Fill the column of a dataframe with random values chosen from a list in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have a data frame with the customers as shown below.

df:

```
id      name     
1       john
2       dan
3       sam
```

also, I have a list as

```
['www.costco.com', 'www.walmart.com']
```

I would like to add a column named `domain` to `df` by randomly selecting the elements from the list.

Expected output:

```
id      name       domain
1       john       www.walmart.com
2       dan        www.costco.com
3       sam        www.costco.com
```

Note: since it is a random selection output may not be the same as always.

It is randomly selecting from the given list of strings, hence it is not same and not duplicate. And it is a specific question and it got great and very specific answers.

Comment: random.choices?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `random.choices`:

```
import random
df['domain'] = random.choices(lst, k=len(df))
```

A sample output:

```
   id  name           domain
0   1  john  www.walmart.com
1   2   dan   www.costco.com
2   3   sam   www.costco.com
```